# Parse Json Array on new lines correctly in StreamDeckSDK

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, streamdeck

I'm trying to take a JSON Array and display the full output, but nicely formatted. (see commented out section) Unfortunately the JSON array returns back with OBJECT then its output. So I stringify to fix the [Object, Object] error I was getting.  But now everything is on one line. How do iterate through the array and put them on new lines?

Second issue I'm having is, I can't do 3 of the same functions as you notice in the uncommented section. I'd like to take each `result` and add a new line in between them.

```
   function setTitleStatus(context, settings) {
        $SD.api.setTitle(context, "Updating...");
        getResults(result => resultCallback(result, context));
    }

    function resultCallback(result, context) {
        if (!result.hasOwnProperty("Object")) {
           $SD.api.setTitle(context, JSON.stringify(result));
           console.log(JSON.stringify(result, '%c%s'));
           return;
        }
        // This is where I'd like all 3 objects to be split on new lines.
        // $SD.api.setTitle(context, result.Platform.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '\n') +
        //     "\n" + result.Platform + " ")
        // $SD.api.setTitle(context, result.PU.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '\n') +
        //     "\n" + result.PU + " ")
        // $SD.api.setTitle(context, result.EA.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '\n') +
        //     "\n" + result.EA + " ")
    }

    function getResults(updateTitleFn) {
        let endPoint = "https://status.robertsspaceindustries.com/static/content/api/v0/systems.en.json";
        $.getJSON(endPoint)
            .done(function (response) {

                updateTitleFn({
                    "Platform": response[0].status,
                    "PU": response[1].status,
                    "EA": response[2].status,
                });

                console.log("Platform", response[0].status)
                console.log("PU", response[1].status)
                console.log("EA", response[2].status)

            })
    }
```

**Update**
If I uncomment the sections this is what it shows. Its hard to tell but whats happening is, its taking replacing `setTitle` three times, and taking the last line. `$SD.api.setTitle(context, result.EA.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '\n') +
         "\n" + result.EA + " ")`
Via Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I assume that the commented code is what you need help fixing. If you uncomment it,  what does your app display? What do you want it to display differently? Please show some screenshots.

Comment: hi there. I've updated my comments, @Code-Apprentice hopefully it makes sense. I want it to display "Platform operational \n
PU degraded-performance \n
EA operational"

Comment: To stringify with multiline and indented output, use `JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2)`. If you don't want indenting, omit the "2".

Comment: Thank you ! @terrymorse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get nicely formatted output from `JSON.stringify`, supply the optional arguments:

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)
```

```js
let arr = ["Pineapple", "Lemon", "Apple", "Orange", "Peach"];

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
  'Stringify default: ' + JSON.stringify(arr) + '\n\n' +
  'Stringify formatted: ' + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```